# How to optimize iteration over pandas dataframe when vectorization is not possible

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, vectorization

I have a rather complex computation to make which I want to optimize. I would leverage pandas/numpy vectorization but not sure if it possible to solve this task with vectorization. Currently I am using pandas dataframe but using for loop to iterate over dataframe.

Task Explanation:

The lookup table gives the mapping. For example the `old` "1" is split between `new` "11" and "12" with the split proportion given as `weight`. 60% of "1" was passed to "11" and 40% was passed to "12".
Another example is where `old` "2" was renamed to `new` "20". So the split ratio here is 100%.
Similarly for `old` "3" which is split into `new` "31", "32", "33".

The actual values for "1", "2", "3" are given in table `df`.  In the resulting table `new_df` the `old` values need to be replaced with `new` by multiplying the respective `weights`/ratio.

I hope this explanation will suffice. The tables below will help more.

1. weights (it is a lookup table)

   ```
   data = {'old':['1','1','2','3','3','3'], 'new':['11','12', '20','31','32','33'], 'Weight': [0.6, 0.4,1 ,0.2, 0.5, 0.3]} 
   weights = pd.DataFrame(data) 
   weights

        old   new    Weight
   0    1     11     0.6
   1    1     12     0.4
   2    2     20     1
   3    3     31     0.2
   4    3     32     0.5
   5    3     33     0.3
   ```
2. df    ( actual data table/ matrix)

   ```
   data = {'A1':['1','1', '1', '2','2','2', '3','3'], 'A2':['1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2'], 'value': [50, 40, 30 ,10, 20, 70, 80, 90]} 
   df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
   df

        A1  A2  value
   0    1   1   50   
   1    1   2   40    
   2    1   3   30     
   3    2   1   10    
   4    2   2   20    
   5    2   3   70    
   6    3   1   80
   7    3   2   90
   ```

new_df  ( resulting dataframe)

```
        A1_new  A2_new  value_new  | calculation (only for explanation)
   0    11      11      18         | 50 * 0.6 * 0.6
   1    12      12      8          | 50 * 0.4 * 0.4
   2    11      12      12         | 50 * 0.6 * 0.4
   3    12      11      12         | 50 * 0.6 * 0.4
   4    11      20      24         | 40 * 1 * 0.6
   5    12      20      16         | 40 * 1 * 0.4
   6    11      31      3.6        | 30 * 0.6 * 0.2
   7    11      32      9          | 30 * 0.6 * 0.5
   8    11      33      5.4        | 30 * 0.6 * 0.3
   9    12      31      2.4        | 30 * 0.4 * 0.2
  10    12      32      6          | 30 * 0.4 * 0.5
  11    12      33      3.6        | 30 * 0.4 * 0.3
   12   31      11      9.6        | 80 * 0.2 * 0.6
   13   32      11      24         | 80 * 0.5 * 0.6
   14   33      11      14.4       | 80 * 0.3 * 0.6 
   15   31      12      6.4        | 80 * 0.2 * 0.4 
   16   32      12      16         | 80 * 0.5 * 0.4 
   17   33      12      9.6        | 80 * 0.3 * 0.4 
   18   31      20      16         | 80 * 0.2 * 1
   19   32      20      40         | 80 * 0.5 * 1
   20   33      20      24         | 80 * 0.3 * 1
```

Below is the code I am using right now which does the job. However, the example I have given is only a sample of data. There are several thousand rows so I need to optimize it somehow.

```
l=[]

for i in range(len(df)) :
    print(i)

    ## check if both A2 and A1 has changes in df. 
    
    if weights['old'].isin([df.loc[i,'A1']]).any().any() == True and weights['old'].isin([df.loc[i,'A2']]).any().any() == True:

            #print('BOTH CHANGED' ,df.loc[i,'A1'], df.loc[i,'A2'])   
            for j in range(len(weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A1']].values)):

                    for k in range(len(weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A2']].values)):
                        n=[None]*3

                        n[0]=weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A1']].values[j][1]
                        n[1]=weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A2']].values[k][1]    
                        n[2]=df.loc[i,'value']*weights.loc[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A1']].values[j][2]*weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A2']].values[k][2]
                    
                        l.append(n)
    
    ## check if only A1 has any changes. 
              
    
    elif weights['old'].isin([df.loc[i,'A1']]).any().any() == True:

                for j in range(len(weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A1']].values)):

                    n=[None]*3

                    n[0]=weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A1']].values[j][1]
                    n[1]=df.loc[i,'A2']
                    n[2]=df.loc[i,'value']*weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A1']].values[j][2]
                

                    l.append(n)  
                    

        
    
    ## check if only A2 has any changes. 

    
    elif weights['old'].isin([df.loc[i,'A2']]).any().any() == True and weights['old'].isin([df.loc[i,'A1']]).any().any() == False:
   


                for j in range(len(weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A2']].values)):
                    #print(j)
                    n=[None]*3
                
                    n[0]=df.loc[i,'A1']
                    n[1]=weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A2']].values[j][1]
                    n[2]=df.loc[i,'value']*weights[weights['old']==df.loc[i,'A2']].values[j][2]
                

                    l.append(n)   


                    
cols =  ['A1_new','A2_new', 'value_new' ]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=cols)
```

Comment: Can you explain how the calculation and lookups are supposed to work?

Comment: I have added the explanation. hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Preface

So as far as I understand, you would like to split up each combination of `(A1, A2)` into all of its possible new combinations `(A1_new, A2_new)` each with their respective new `value` based on their weights.

From your desired output I found a small inconsistency, when you have the first row:

```
     A1  A2  value
0    1   1   50
```

is it really true that you would only these two resulting rows:

```
        A1_new  A2_new  value_new  
   0    11      11      30        
   1    12      12      20
```

and not four rows (e.g. all possible pairs)

```
    A1_new  A2_new  value_new
0       11      11       18.0
1       11      12       12.0
2       12      11       12.0
3       12      12        8.0
```

if that is really the case, please add a comment about the exact rule when this happens and I will edit my answer.

## Solution

As said above, the following solutions uses all available pairs of `A1` and `A2` replacements. The general idea is to "replace" all old values of the columns using an inner join on both `A` columns and then compute the new value based on the joined weights.

```py
df = df\
    .merge(weights, left_on="A1", right_on="old") \
    .drop(columns=["A1", "old"]) \
    .rename(columns={"new": "A1_new"}) \
    .merge(weights, left_on="A2", right_on="old") \
    .drop(columns=["A2", "old"]) \
    .rename(columns={"new": "A2_new"}) 

df["value_new"] = df["value"] * df["Weight_x"] * df["Weight_y"]
df = df.drop(columns=["value", "Weight_x", "Weight_y"])
```

## Resulting data

```
    A1_new  A2_new  value_new
0       11      11       18.0
1       11      12       12.0
2       12      11       12.0
3       12      12        8.0
4       20      11        6.0
5       20      12        4.0
6       31      11        9.6
7       31      12        6.4
8       32      11       24.0
9       32      12       16.0
10      33      11       14.4
11      33      12        9.6
12      11      20       24.0
13      12      20       16.0
14      20      20       20.0
15      31      20       18.0
16      32      20       45.0
17      33      20       27.0
18      11      31        3.6
19      11      32        9.0
20      11      33        5.4
21      12      31        2.4
22      12      32        6.0
23      12      33        3.6
24      20      31       14.0
25      20      32       35.0
26      20      33       21.0
```

Comment: @BStadtbauer, thanks for your answer.  It is my mistake, I would like to split up each combination of (A1, A2) into all of its possible new combinations (A1_new, A2_new). However, I don't get where you calculated Weight_X and Weight_Y. Did you miss to add some part of the code ?

Comment: @Jio, so this is done automatically by pandas. After the first `.merge()` the `df` will get a `Weight` column (from the `weights` df). When doing the second `.merge()`, you would add an additinal column `Weight`, which would be a name collision. `pandas` now automatically adds suffixes `_x` to the left df and `_y` to the right df. See the documentation of [.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) - the argument is `suffixes`